# How to adjust longtable horizontal padding for first and last columns only

Tags: longtable, columns

I'm reading `longtable` documentation trying to find a way to change the horizontal padding / column spacing for only the first and last columns.

As shown in the image (red line), default spacing is creating a "gap" that's quite prominent when using the horizontal line separators (I'm using `booktabs` package for separators):

[image]

I'd like to pull this left to the beginning where the blue line is, and push the last text column all the way to the right. But at the same time keep what's in the middle with some breathing space.

So far I tried adjusting `\tabcolsep`:

```
\setlength\tabcolsep{2.5pt}
```

But as expected, as I approach the left margin, the spacing between the remaining columns disappears as well, making the text illegible.

Is it possible to control this padding on per column basis?

And please don't hold it against me that I'm not submitting the full source code. It's more of a general question.

Comment: Add @{} before the first and after the last column specifier as in \begin{longtable} {@{}lll@{}}  for a longtable with 3 l type columns.

Comment: Thanks for replying @leandriis. My table is using the following specifiers:
{
>{\RaggedRight\hspace*{0pt}}p{2.5cm} 
>{\RaggedRight}p{2cm} 
>{\RaggedRight}p{4cm} 
>{\RaggedRight\itshape}p{3cm} 
>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm} 
} 
Is there a way to use @{} together with RaggedRight?

Comment: Sure. `\begin{longtable}{@{} >{\RaggedRight.....>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm} @{} }` should work. Just place the `@{}` before the first and after the last column specifier.

Comment: I just gave it a try @leandriis. It worked like a charm! Many thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is solved by comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can `pull` longtable to the left as defined in the book with the help of `[l]` in the horizontal definition`HPos` of the table

```
\begin{longtable} [HPos] {column definition }
. . . & . . . & . . . \\
\end{longtable}
```

See the example number 3 in the image below

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply js bibra. My question is related to internal rather than external margins (i.e. cell padding vs. table margins). More so, table barely fits \textwidth so I would have no room to move it left or right anyway.